# how to search multiple word in the same file using ruby and the get the output which contains those words

Tags: ruby

I am trying to search for multiple words at the same time in ruby. But it is not returning any output(value). I should return the lines which contains /java and java versions

Anyone help me

Here is my code:

```
logfile = "/home/weblogic/javaapp.txt"  
java_count = 0
if File.exist? '/home/weblogic/javaapp.txt'
  log = Facter::Util::FileRead.read(logfile)
  unless log.nil?
    log.each_line do |line|
      case 
      when line.include?('/java')
        java_count += 1
        java_path = line.split(/ /)[0]
      when line.include?('java version')
        java_version = line.split('"')[1]
        Facter.add("java_u01_weblogic_foundversion#{java_count}u01_#{java_count}_path") do
          setcode do
            java_version + java_path
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
  Facter.add("java_u01_weblogic_foundversion_count") do
    setcode do
      java_count
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my text file

```
/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

I am trying to get the output informations like this
/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java  by searching with the /java

"1.7.0_72"   --> by searching with the word 'java version'  using one text file for both words

Comment: I haven't got what you are actually trying to get from the text... Do you want to get all the java versions in the text file or what?

Comment: Hi,Yes i want java versions and paths in that file

Comment: Please take the time to correctly indent your code. As is its a mess, and that makes it difficult to read it. When things are difficult to decipher, you discourage potential answerers for helping you.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at 'regular expressions' in Ruby. This should work for 'java version' (I haven't tested it)

```
str = IO.read('file.txt')    
# Java version
match = str.match(/java version "([^"]+)"/)
puts match[1]
# Java path
match = str.match(/^([^ ]+\/java)$/)
puts match[1]
```

Comment: Hi Max, I am having this error, when trying your code: error unmatched close parenthesis: /java version "[^"]+)"/

Comment: mmm... that seems to work in rubular. I don't get what the problem is. Check this http://rubular.com/r/QFhj2qm7Eg

Comment: Hi, is there a way to search for path also using match statement

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the lines containing "/java" and their version, then, in your sample it's only necessary to find lines containing "/java":

```
lines = [ 
  '/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java',
  'java version "1.7.0_72"',
  'Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)',
  'Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)',
  '/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java',
  'java version "1.7.0_72"',
  'Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)',
  'Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)',
]

lines.grep(%r!/java!) 
# => ["/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java", "/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/bin/java"]
```

---

If you want to capture the version strings, the first thing to know is that those are some of the hardest things to find because there is so much variance in the format. The fact that you are only interested in Java version strings helps as they're somewhat standard. A pattern like

```
/\d+\.[a-z\d._-]+/
```

will help.

Here's a [Rubular proof](http://rubular.com/r/UJTJ8eyrQI) of the matching.

`a-z` is the range of possible revision types, such as alpha, beta, etc. You get to figure out what those are and correct the pattern. Failing to do so opens up the pattern to false-positive hits which will return bad data back to you.

```
lines.map{ |s| s[/\d+\.[a-z\d._-]+/] }
# => ["1.7.0_72",
#     "1.7.0_72",
#     "1.7.0_72-b14",
#     "24.72-b04",
#     "1.7.0_72",
#     "1.7.0_72",
#     "1.7.0_72-b14",
#     "24.72-b04"]
```

Or

```
lines.grep(%r!/java!).map{ |s| s[/\d+\.[a-z\d._-]+/] }
# => ["1.7.0_72", "1.7.0_72"]
```

Comment: Hi Tin, i want the line which java versions too. Let me know

Comment: Your question isn't clear about that. Please rephrase the question so everyone understands exactly what you want. Do that by showing the input lines, and which lines should be found, and what data you want from those lines.

Comment: Hi, i am having issue when trying your code  by placing java_path = line.grep(%r!/java!) like this and error is  undefined method `grep' for "/u01/java/jdk1.7.0_72/jre/bin/java\n":String

Comment: Read the code carefully. I'm not using `line`, it's `lines`. `lines` is an array. You can't use `grep` on a String.

Comment: Hi, Here is how i changed but still having issue. logfile = "/home/weblogic/javaapp.txt" java_path = logfile.grep(%r!/java!)

Comment: Error: Could not retrieve local facts: undefined method `grep' for "/home/weblogic/javaapp.txt":String

Comment: Again, look *VERY* carefully at my code. What class is `lines`? Compare that to the class Ruby is telling you doesn't have `grep`. You can see that my code is finding the information from the *lines* (hint, hint, hint). Each of those *lines* is a what? (hint, hint, hint)